# How to solve integration equation with constant bounds (edited)

Tags: probability, integration, numerical-methods

I edit the question according to the comment of [G. Sassatelli](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/228113/g-sassatelli) (thank so much for your contribution)

I would like to find $B(x)$ of $F_{a,b}(M)=\int_0^M B(x)\bar{F}_{a,b}(M−x)dx$ where $F_{a,b}(⋅)$ and $\bar{F}_{a,b}(⋅)$ are respectively the gamma distribution and the associated survival function (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution)). $F_{a,b}(⋅)$ is expressed by $F_{a,b}(x)=\int_x^\infty f_{\alpha,\beta}(u)du$, where $f_{\alpha,\beta}(u)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\beta^\alpha u^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta u}1_{u\geq 0}$ is a gamma density function with parameter $\alpha$ and $\beta$. I expect that $B(x)$ is a continuous and unique function on $[0,M)$.

====== original question ======

I would like to solve $f(x)$ from the following general equation $\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx =c$, where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are constants, $g(x)$ is a known and continuous function on $[a,b]$. Do you have any idea to find $f(x)$.

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Tuan

Comment: What kind of "solution" would you expect, say, for $g\equiv 1$? There are always a ton of such functions (for instance, any suitable multiple of most continuous functions).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually, I would like to find $B(x)$ of $F_{a,b}(M)=\int_0^M B(x)\bar{F}_{a,b}(M-x) dx$ where $F_{a,b}(\cdot)$ and $\bar{F}_{a,b}(\cdot)$ are respectively the gamma distribution and the associated survival function ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution)). I expect that  $B(x)$ is unique.

Comment: Why do you expect the solution to be unique? If we think of the equation as an inner product $<f,g> = \int fg \, dx,$ then it make sense to me that there are probably a lot of functions $f$ such that $<f,g> = c.$

Comment: @HUYNHKhacTuan I think you should edit your post to make your original problem the actual question. Your first choice of formulation is too general - to the point of being just generic. It also fails to capture a couple of constraints of the problem which *might* play a very important role in the solution being somehow unique: 1) $a,b,c$ are related. 2) $g$ is related to the function $c(b)$ 3) [most important] you are looking for **a** $f$ which satisfies the identity **for all** $b$, not for *one* $f$ *for each* choice of $a,b,c$.

Comment: Basically: A) "Is it true that $\forall g,\forall a,\forall b,\forall c,\exists f,\,\cdots?$" Of course! There are infinitely many. B) "Is it true that $\forall g,\exists f,\forall a,\forall b,\forall c,\,\cdots?$" Uhmm... Might be?

Comment: You are asking (A), but you want (B). While it is true that, *if* (B) has a solution and *if* for each instance of the problem (A) there is a unique solution, then the solutions to (A) can be patched together to form the unique solution of (B). But the two problems are completely different.